# Performance of an index on a column which is always null

Tags: mysql, performance, orm

I'm using a custom ORM framework which creates a column for all tables in the database called 'owningObject'. The column is a `varchar(255)` and the value is always `NULL`. The ORM is also creating an index on this column for all my tables.

Is there any performance risk to having an index on a column when the value is always `NULL`? I'm considering removing the index from these tables (I can't remove the column itself because the ORM requires it).

Comment: I suggest you through the ORM to the `NULL` bin ;) Seriously though, having a column which is always a single value (NULL or not) is just a waste of space. Not much but a waste. And having an index on it? A serious waste of space. Which ORM is this?

Comment: The ORM framework is part of http://www.mv3d.com/trac/ but I think it's just that we're not using that ownership column in our code. I'll remove the indices, thanks.

Comment: Grrr...  Yet another 3rd party software trying to do more harm that good.